# How to add internal fillets in hand drawn shapes in masses?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, automation, corners

I've got this thing I drew using the brush tool that's suppose to be a panel for some project of mine and I'm trying to get some nice defined fillets to each hole:

[image]

What would be the easiest way to achieve it as efficiently as possible because I believe there are at least 100 corners there even if there's a way to select it and that's no task for a human.

Comment: Points for the sneaky way you convinced us you're a human. Could you please check this checkbox though?

Answer (score 3):

It would drive me crazy if I had to alter each corner manually. So... I'd use a more global method....

- Expand Strokes (Object > Expand / Copy *only* outer compound rectangle for later use)
- Merge shapes (Pathfinder Panel > Merge)
- Apply Effect (Effect > Stylize > Round Corners)
- Expand Effect (Object > Expand Appearance)
- Fix Outer 4 corners (Paste rectangle, Pathfinder > Unite)

[image]

The last 2 steps merely square off the outer 4 corners again. You could do that manually by removing the curves and aligning anchors if desired.

Comment: Love it. The reason I'd specified multi-select with the direct select tool was that I presumed that certain more acute angles might need different fillet radii for ease of manufacture, and I wanted to demonstrate a method which left more control to the OP - but I completely agree with you - absent that need, I'd go loopy doing a bunch  of corners individually too - your answer is excellent, IMHO.

Comment: Great one! thank you very much for the huge effort! I eventually just "Expand appearance" the traced then round corners expand appearance again and merged them in the end.

Answer (score 0):

- Select all
- Menu **Object** -> **Expand**
- **Shape Builder Tool**

[image]

- Choose a fill color and click the holes

[image: grid]

Comment: Danielillo - the OP said "fillets" not "fills" - that's a US CAD draughting term for the rounding of a corner used to make a design more manufacturable... so your answer gets them halfway there - they need to Pathfinder>Union all the black, then select all corners and round the corners uniformly with the rounded corner tool.

Comment: Ah , ok, didn't get it right.

Comment: Well this is also a useful thing to know thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take Danielillo's excellent answer, then use Pathfinder to union all the black elements together. Once you've done this select all the corners using the direct selection tool, and then use the rounded corner tool to give the fillets you prefer or need for the given manufacturing method.

[image: Like so]